# How do I escape a single quote within data to be displayed in Highcharts using php?

Tags: php

I am trying to display a chart including a tooltip displaying a string which can contain an apostrophe (single quote). The data is retrieved from a database using php.

My data for each point in the series to be displayed consists of an x value (datetime), y value (numeric), a distance, and a name (string) to be displayed in a tooltip. All works well until the name read from the database includes a single quote e.g. Tegg's, at which point the chart doesn't display. I presume this is because the JSON_ENCODE doesn't escape a single quote that is within a single quoted string. I can't escape the single quote before the JSON_ENCODE as it then escapes the escape character. How can I get this to work?

My code is as follows:

```
foreach ($this->hcRides as $ride)
{
    $point['x'] = strtotime($ride->event_date) * 1000;
    $point['y'] = $ride->ranking_points;
    $point['name'] = "'$ride->event_name'";
    $point['distance'] = "'$ride->distance'";

    array_push($countingRideData, json_encode($point));
}

// Strip the double-quotes out of the JSON
$countingRideDataString = str_replace('"', "", join($countingRideData, ','));
```

I then echo $countingRideDataString as the data in the series.

```
hcoptions.series.push({
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Counting Rides',
                data: [<?php echo $countingRideDataString; ?>],
                color: '#222845',
                tooltip: {
                    customTooltip: function() {
                        return '<table class="tt-chart-table"><thead><tr><th>' + this.key + '</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>' + this.point.distance + '</td></tr><tr><td><b>' + this.y + '</b> points</td></tr></tbody></table>'
                    }
                },
                zIndex: 2
            });
```

Comment: Try adding the flag `JSON_HEX_APOS` as the second argument to `json_encode()`. [Check the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) for more available flags.

Comment: I would suggest that you don't json encode the data in the loop. Just add the data to the array as a normal array and then just encode the final array. Also, removing all `"` from the final json data will make it invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_encode()` is exactly the tool you need here but you seem to be fighting against it, trying to undo its job and replacing it with manual work on your side.

1. Create a single data structure normally. Don't attempt to encode anything. E.g.

   ```
   // Don't do this:
   $point['name'] = "'$ride->event_name'";
   // Do this instead:
   $point['name'] = $ride->event_name;
   ```

   ```
   // Don't do this:
   array_push($countingRideData, json_encode($point));
   // Do this instead:
   array_push($countingRideData, $point);
   ```

   ```
   // Remove this altogether:
   $countingRideDataString = str_replace('"', "", join($countingRideData, ','));
   ```
2. Encode **once**, at the very end:

   ```
       // Don't do this:
       data: [<?php echo $countingRideDataString; ?>],
       // Do this instead:
       data: <?php echo json_encode(countingRideData); ?>,
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I can't get this to work. Looking at the Highcharts documentation the data structure shouldn't include double quotes around the attribute name, but using the code you've suggested above places both the attribute name and value in double quotes. E.g. https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-objects/ data: [{
            name: 'Point 1',
            color: '#00FF00',
            y: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Point 2',
            color: '#FF00FF',
            y: 5
        }]

Comment: Got it sorted now - not sure what I had done wrong with your suggested code, but all working now. Thank you!

Comment: That's how JavaScript syntax works. Object key identifiers need to be quoted when they contain certain characters (such as white spaces) but otherwise quoting is optional (that implies it isn't disallowed).